# Painless deployment of a Django app (port from Drupal). Do I have to switch to a VPS?

Tags: hosting, vps, deployment, django

I'm about to complete porting my Drupal based community site to Django. My Drupal site is hosted at a shared hosting (Dreamhost) for last 4 years, and stability & performance has been satisfactory. The site gets around 5k unique visitors with 70-80k page views a day.

This will be my first deployment of a Django application and I'm not comfortable with managing my own VPS. I use Ubuntu as a dev. server, but I don't have experience with it at the production env.

I have an unrelated internal CRM app (Django) that I host with Webfaction. However security and performance isn't an issue as it's only accessed by 5 people.

Unfortunately, I don't have much time to learn and maintain a VPS at this moment. I would like to know if I can host a site with this much traffic at Webfaction's shared environment?

How would performance differ in comparison to Linode or Slicehost?

Google AppEngine isn't an option at the moment as I'll be using my current Postgresql database.

Answer (score 1):

You could still use Dreamhost, they do support Django. Its even installed on all their servers now. See http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Django

-- EDIT:

Now that heroku support Django, check http://heroku.com/ out :)